# Can the javascript attached to XBL control know what mode the form is in?

Tags: javascript, orbeon

Can the JS code determine if the form is in 'design' mode? As opposed to 'run' mode.

Answer (score 0):

First, I should say that in most cases, you'd like your XBL component to behave exactly the same whether it is running in Form Builder or in a published form. But I understand there are cases where this isn't possible.

- In JavaScript, which I think you were asking about, there isn't an "official API", but you could use something like `ORBEON.jQuery('.fb-main').is('*')`.
- In XPath, there is an [RFE to add an XPath function for this](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2231), and until that is implemented, you can use a [workaround](http://discuss.orbeon.com/xbl-component-am-I-in-the-builder-tp4659909p4659912.html).

Comment: Orbeon Forms 2016.2 will have a function to support this, called `fr:is-design-time()`.

Answer (score 0):

I put together this little function so the control can know what mode it's being used in. `$` is jquery.

```
function formMode() {
    var view = $( '#fr-view' );
    if ( view.hasClass( 'fr-mode-test' ) ) return 'test'
    if ( view.hasClass( 'fr-mode-view' ) ) return 'view'
    if ( view.hasClass( 'fr-mode-edit' ) ) 
        if ( view.find( '.fb-main' ).length > 0 ) return 'design'
    return 'edit'
}
```